# Which would be more correct and faster in C++11: switch-case or if( .. || .. || .. )?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

I'm trying to build simple lexical analyzer - lexer. The part I'm working on now is tokenizer. I'm writing function which determines separators (whitespaces, tabs, newlines(CR, LF)) in the input sequence. So the question is which code is more correct:

The code with switch-case statement:

```
bool isWhitespace(wchar_t &symbol) {
    
    switch (symbol) {
        
        case L' ':
        case L'\t':
        case L'\r':
        case L'\n':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        
    }
    
}
```

Or the code with if(.. || .. || ..) statement:

```
bool isWhitespace(wchar_t &symbol) {
    
    if (symbol == L' ' ||
        symbol == L'\t' ||
        symbol == L'\r' ||
        symbol == L'\n') {

        return true;

    }
    
    return false;
    
}
```

And which one would be faster?

---

UPD

Well, the result of assambler generated code and speed tests are:

For `switch-case`:

```
__Z12isWhitespaceRw:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzwl  (%eax), %eax
    movzwl  %ax, %eax
    cmpl    $13, %eax
    je  L18
    cmpl    $13, %eax
    jg  L19
    subl    $9, %eax
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    ja  L17
    jmp L18
L19:
    cmpl    $32, %eax
    jne L17
L18:
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp L20
L17:
    movl    $0, %eax
L20:
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

And for `if`:

```
__Z12isWhitespaceRw:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzwl  (%eax), %eax
    cmpw    $32, %ax
    je  L22
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzwl  (%eax), %eax
    cmpw    $9, %ax
    je  L22
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzwl  (%eax), %eax
    cmpw    $13, %ax
    je  L22
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzwl  (%eax), %eax
    cmpw    $10, %ax
    jne L23
L22:
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp L24
L23:
    movl    $0, %eax
L24:
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I'm not an assambler mega expert but looks like switch-case code has more jumps and less compare operations.

And speed measures:

## 1

Switch-case: `%time = 7.7`, `self = 0.01`

If: `%time = 46.2`, `self = 0.06`

## 2

Switch-case: `%time = 34.6`, `self = 0.03`

If: `%time = 34.6`, `self = 0.03`

---

UPD #2

Yes, Unicode. Isn't it so obvious if looking at code?!

Comment: Which is faster - test it and see (IO is probably your limiting factor so pre-optimising code is not useful) .  As you are using Unicode what about all the extra Unicode "space" characters?

Comment: @RichardCritten unicode extra "spaces" are not preset here in purpose to make code easier to view.
"test it and see" - well I hope someone did it before.

Comment: @PRIGORYAN A SCA tool would probably complain about your fall through `case` statements.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ AFAIK this is correct representation for not duplicate `return true` after every `case`

Comment: @PRIGORYAN As mentioned an SCA tool might complain without showing that the fall through is intentional (e.g. using a comment like `// falls through`). As for your question: I would expect a high probability that the generated assembler code for both variants will be exactly the same.

Comment: There are **many** more ways to write that code. I'd go for something far less verbose, e.g. using a `std::string` or, if suitable, one of the standard library's whitespace checker functions. Anyway an `if` to decide which of `false` or `true` to return, is just silly, needlessly verbose and awkward: don't do that, please.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I need broad sollution because input symbols can be anything. And `std::string` is not suitable because of Unicode. Maybe `std::wstring` but i trying to find more compact sollution because `std::wstring` has a lot of code I do not really need

Comment: @PRIGORYAN: When you have extra requirements such as dealing with special Unicode whitespace characters these **requirements should go in the question**, not in comments. All of the whitespace characters shown in your question are ASCII.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf as you can see in question there is "wchar_t" everywhere which is clearly shows that code is used for Unicode input.

Comment: Fwiw in my testing the `ifs` are about 20% faster.

Comment: @Galik so looks like usage of `if` is more correct and clear. And speed can differ depending on settings and machines.

Comment: @PRIGORYAN I wouldn't say either was "more correct". I was actually surprised the `ifs` were faster in my tests. It may change with a different number of symbols to check. I just thought it worth pointing out that the `switch` may not always be faster.

Comment: If speed is super important then it may be worth checking the unicode spec for ways to quickly identify a unicode whitespace code point.

Comment: @Galik not super important. But it is interesting to investigate which sollution is better

Comment: @PRIGORYAN have you checked that all unicode space characters are a single wide char.  UTF-16 is not fixed width.  If any are then the `case` approach will not be possible.

Comment: I used wrong word in description. There is set of separators and some of them are represented in code. So I do not need to chech all the UTF-16 space characters.
Btw. input sequence is UTF-8 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct but the switch/case version will produce warnings with some compilers.

Both are likely to create the same (or similar) machine code. So there is no significant performance difference.

The second version makes clearer what is happening. This is not a typical use case for switch/case but that's just my opinion.

The order of comparisons does have an effect on performance. You should start with the most frequent case, then the second and so on. This will reduce the number of comparisons.

Comment: Well looks like switch-case is a bit faster. And my GCC 5.1.0 is not producing any warnings with flags: `-std=gnu++11 -w -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pg -pipe`

Comment: How did you do the speed measurement? I find it hard to believe that `if` is slower by a factor of 5. Another question: Did you use any optimization settings?

Comment: No, any optimizations are turned off. The flags specified above are the only used.
Speed measurement is done by gprof while compiling with `-pg`and running the code 100000 times for 10 different symbols.
But when I changed an orded of functions - the results become nearly same. So this might be measuring error